# How do I test two ParseUsers or ParseObjects for equality?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am trying to compare a ParseUser that is stored as the Author to the ParseUser returned by ParseUser.getCurrentUser().  It appears that they the following will not necessarily return true:

```
ParseUser author = post.getParseUser("author");
author.getObjectID().equals(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectID()); // true
author.equals(ParseUser.getCurrentUser()); // false
```

I'd rather not always compare the object IDs because it makes it hard to compare objects that are not yet saved (which presumably should only be equal if they are the same actual instance).